# I can't install Tkinter or tkinter. I tried every code and reinstall TCL/TK too. But still got an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I try every solution on stackover and many other sites. But it's still giving same faults. I even couldn't install it.

```
C:\Users\***\Google Drive\Python>pip install tkinter
Collecting tkinter
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter

C:\Users\***\Google Drive\Python>pip install Tkinter
Collecting Tkinter
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Tkinter

C:\Users\***\Google Drive\Python>pip install Tk
Collecting Tk
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Tk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Tk

C:\Users\***\Google Drive\Python>pip install tk
Collecting tk
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Varolan bir bağlantı uzaktaki bir ana bilgisayar tarafından zorla kapatıldı', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tk/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tk

C:\Users\***\Google Drive\Python>pip install python3-tk
Collecting python3-tk
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-tk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python3-tk
```

Comment: You cannot install tkinter with pip. You need to install a version of python that includes tkinter.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are on Windows, in which case you have tkinter already (if you run 2.7 or above). It seems you use Python 3 so run `import tkinter`. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter)

If you are on Linux/Mac/similar variant then you need to run `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`.  It is not a `pip` package and cannot be installed in this way.

If the `python -m tkinter` command fails on Windows then your installation is broken, or if on Linux/Mac/Similar then the command above should work.

---

On Windows there are two things that could have gone  wrong:

- Your installation is broken
- You forgot to check option for tkinter

If your installation is broken then reinstalling your should work, but more likely you forgot to check the `tck/tk and IDLE` option when installing.  To check or to install re-run your installer and press `modify`.  You should see a box like the following.  Ensure then the `tck/tk and IDLE` does have a tick on it:

[image]

And press `Next`

Comment: I am using Python3.6.3 on Windows. Actualy I am trying to use matplotlib. But when I try to import it gives me no module name tkinter.

`Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>`

Comment: `C:\Users\asus>python -m tkinter
C:\Python36\python.exe: No module named tkinter`

Comment: @MahirYıldızhan  I think I have found the problem you have.  Could you please take a look at my edited answer

Comment: Just run the installer again , press the "Modify" button. Any existing modules will not get removed. Close your IDE first though.

Comment: Thanks. `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` solved my `no module named PySimpleGUI` problem on Linux Mint. The fact that the real problem, is hidden, makes life a little confusing.

Comment: Thanks.
And @HughBarnard I had the same problem, until I found this thread :-)

Answer (score 0):

So, as a user on Windows 10, I've mainly stuck to using just good ol' IDLE ... I must've gotten bored this weekend and for some crazy reason, decided to download and install Visual Studio. Obviously, being unfamiliar with it, I ran into some difficulties and confusion - one of them being VS insisting on using IT'S python environment rather than the more updated and latest one I already have installed.

This would be fine, especially since I could add ***only*** the packages that I needed to import, however... Visual Studio runs into the same issue described here. No form or fashion of attempting to install tkinter works ... python3-tk or otherwise.

I HAVE, however, worked around the issue in my particular case ... by adding the IDLE installation I already had to the Visual Studio Python environments. Apparently this only worked because IDLE Python installs tkinter as part of it's standard library.

I'm still curious and would like to know what needs to be done for *non* - IDLE installations, though... I didn't realize how big of a hassle this was before now. The most promising answer I could find leads to the Tcl developers:

https://www.activestate.com/products/tcl/

It appears as though it may require manual installation.